# Some whiteboard program specialized for "typing" with latex support

Tags: reference-request, computer-programs, latex

Answers to the [Previou question](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/18030/online-whiteboard-application-with-simple-latex-support?newreg=b72e64a72b7f4f1fb764e498d8381b83) seem to suggest some whiteboard programs with latex support.

However, my impression is that they are mostly designed for "handwriting" with some electrical pen.

I wonder if there exists some program that resembles the webpage where I am writing my question now. That is, I "type" my question here, including formulas, and the output is instantly shown below in the latex format.

Could anyone pleaes help me?

Comment: *I wonder if there exists some program that resembles the webpage where I am writing my question now. That is, I "type" my question here, including formulas, and the output is instantly shown below in the latex format.* Why not just screenshare that very webpage to the whiteboard and use some free screen annotation tool if you want to write other stuff on top of it?

Comment: @JustinSkycak What is free screen annotation??

Comment: I just meant a screen annotation tool that's free. There are tools that you can use to "handwrite" on the screen of your computer. Here are some examples: https://www.thewindowsclub.com/best-free-software-to-draw-on-screen-in-windows-10-pc

Comment: [Jupyter notebooks](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/193872/126851) allow markdown and latex (and also plotting figures with python).

Comment: The way I have dealt with this is to have a LaTeX-to-PNG converter open in one tab; type my LaTeX there, and then drag and drop it into my whiteboard on another tab. I remember using https://latex2png.com for that purpose, but it looks like that site isn't working now; https://latex2image.joeraut.com/ seems to be a good replacement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gosh, the very platform where you are asking your question supports MathJax.  As you start writing an answer like I am doing now, $\LaTeX$ and math equations $$x^2+x-1=0$$ get rendered in a preview box below. Try it!

Now look at the MathJax demo page.

https://www.mathjax.org/#demo

You can make your own interactive LaTeX MathJax interface like what you find on StackExchange by making an html file on your local computer with the syntax shown in the image below, then open the file with your browser. Make sure that when you make the file with your text editor, you use plain text, not RTF. Make sure the extension for your file is .html

After you open the file with your browser and start typing math code, use   \( and \) for delimiters, not dollar signs!

Here is the image. Note: I tried to paste the text into here, but the indentations got lost, so I will settle for a screenshot of the html file. If you are interested, ask me in a comment and I can post a link to the html file so you can save it to your computer.

[image]

Here is the simple interface I get when I open the file with a web browser and start typing math.

[image]

But when I need to do what you are describing, I usually use Jupyter notebooks in Google Colab.

Answer (score 0):

Xournal++ supports inline Latex. Would that do what you want?

https://xournalpp.github.io/